# How to update specific JSON object array inside JSON file?

Tags: php, json, file

I have a JSON object array `abc_def_ghi` present in the json file `../hello/xyz.json`. The content inside the json file is:

```
{
    "abc_def_ghi": ["nada", "no", "yes", "nada", "nada", "no"],
    "world_status": null
}
```

Below is how I am loading the json in my variable:

```
if (file_exists('../hello/xyz.json')) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../hello/xyz.json'));
}
```

I have a code below which is addding a default value (on specific condition) in the JSON object array. Now I need to overwrite my JSON file with this new content.

```
if ((date('j')==29)) {
    $data->abc_def_ghi = array_fill(0, count($data->abc_def_ghi) , nada);  // Line A
    file_put_contents('../hello/xyz.json', $data);
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I tried above code but somehow it is not overwriting my file but it deleted all the contents of the file.

After adding default value, my JSON should look like this in the file:

```
{
    "abc_def_ghi": ["nada", "nada", "nada", "nada", "nada", "nada"],
    "world_status": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `json_encode` the data before you write it:

```
file_put_contents('../hello/xyz.json', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: @john: Try it and you tell me

Comment: @Every Hi, I hope all is well. I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691611/how-to-make-a-button-execute-a-php-script). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.