# How to make a button execute a php script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, popup

How to make a html button execute a php script ?

I am working on a login system where only one user can login and whenever other users try to login, it should give them the warning pop up message saying `another user is already logged in - Do you want to take over from them?`

- If `userA` is already logged in and `userB` tries to login then it should show on the popup as `userA is already logged in, do you want to take over?`.
- Now for `userA` behind the scene, we will take away write access and show them another popup message that your write access is revoked.

Second point I can handle it later on but as of now I am focus on doing the point one. Below is my code in which I am trying to achieve the first point at `LINE A` -

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_pass']) && $_POST['user_login'] == 1) {
    //Assigning posted values to variables.
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];

    //Checking the values are existing in the database or not
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT user_pass FROM userspanel WHERE user_name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user_from_db = $result->fetch_object();

    if ($user_from_db && password_verify($password, $user_from_db->user_pass)) {

        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM trace_users where open='true'";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if($result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
                    if($row['open'] == "true") {
                        if(!isset($_SESSION['pageadmin'])) {
                            $message = "user " . $row['user_name'] . " is logged in. Do you want to take over ?";
                            // LINE A
                            // how to show pop up button which shows $message on it
                            // and add action on ok and cancel button here?
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else{
                $_SESSION['pageadmin'] = true;
                $open = "true";
                $read_access = "1";
                $write_access = "1";
                $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET open=?, read_access=?, write_access=? WHERE user_name=?");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $open, $read_access, $write_access, $username);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "Invalid username and password";
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the following tasks but I am confused on how to achieve it -

- At `LINE A`, I want to show a pop up message saying `"Previous user is logged in. Do you want to take over?"` with Ok and Cancel buttons.
- Once I click on `Ok` button on that pop up message then I want to execute certain code in php let's say print `hello world` for now and if I click the `cancel` button on that pop then I don't want to do anything.

In short, I want to achieve two things:

**1.** Create a popup message with Ok and Cancel buttons at Line A. 
**2.** On clicking Ok button, I want to execute php script and on clicking Cancel button I don't want anything to happen.

Comment: Unless you really need a history of logged in user, then that logic could be in place but not important to the current problem. A table containing *only* the current logged in user would be easier to implement.

Comment: "Pop up" is kind of vague. Do you mean a JS modal, or an HTML/CSS modal? Regardless, either method will need to submit a form which tells the server, essentially, "log in this user and let them take over". The problem with any approach is that what if *another* user had also been sitting on the same modal, and submits it a fraction of a second later? Which of the two latest users gets priority? Sure, you can always make it a simple case of "king of the hill" (latest person in bumps out whoever was there), but that might not be your intended behavior.

Comment: @kmoser JS modal or HTML/CSS modal both will work. I think multiple users accessing the form at the same time is an issue but we only have 5-6 users (not too many) accessing that form so we can think of it later maybe. On clicking ok button, i want to execute particular php code and on clicking cancel button I don't want to do anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for consulting me :) Do you really want only one user to be logged in, or do you want only one ADMIN to be logged in? And does user getting kicked need to get a message like "someone took over"?

Comment: Making a button execute PHP code can be done two ways: either have the button submit a form where the `action` is your PHP script, or have the button make an AJAX call to a PHP script.

Comment: @Pilan Hi, I want only one user to login at one time. Let us suppose User A is logged in. When 2nd user tries to login then the message should be displayed as "User A is currently logged in. Do you want to take over ?" 

The reason why I am trying to achieve that so that we can prevent two users from overwriting each other's changes.

Comment: @kmoser Hi, sounds good. Which one is easy to implement ? My ultimate goal is that on clicking ok button, I want to execute particular php and on clicking cancel button I don't want anything to happen.

Comment: Ok, but what about User B (who is about to get kicked, when User A presses "OK")? Do you need a message for him? Like "User A took over". Otherwise he will think something went wrong and login again and kick User A, when he takes over again.

Comment: @Pilan Let's say UserA is logged in and another user let's say UserB tries to login at the same time then UserB will get a message that "UserA is logged in. Do you want to take over ?". When UserB clicks ok button then UserB should be 
able to login and UserA write access will be revoked. Also, UserA will get a message that UserB is currently editing the form.

Comment: This system will be a mess if you are not maintaining who is changing what... But to answer your question, any JS modal plug in will fit the job. If the user clicks ok, send the request. Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @itachi I will try my best to create the best reliable system. I am wondering if you can give me a pointer how I can create a JS modal that will send the request on clicking ok button.

Comment: @itachi are you around ?

Comment: you can create form there using html or just call js function to show confirm box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic scenario:

- Store currently authenticated user's unique **id** and **time** in a `.txt` file in the following format (as JSON):

```
json_encode(['user_id' => 1, 'created_at' => (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

- Check the stored `user_id` and `created_at` fields in the file when a user attempts to sign in.
- If the file is empty, log the user in and write user's unique id and time to the file.
- If the file is ***not*** empty and `user_id` field is same as the `id` of the user who attempts to log in and `created_at` field is not older than 12 hours ago (or your custom logic), just update `created_at` field in the file and log the user in.
- If the file is ***not*** empty and `user_id` field is same as the `id` of the user who attempts to log in, but passed more than 12 hours (or your custom logic), ask the user if he/she want to take over another user.
- If the file is ***not*** empty and `user_id` field is ***not*** same as the `id` of the user who attempts to log in ask the user if he/she want to take over another user.

### Basic implementation:

1. Create a `.txt` file in your project directory.
2. Add these helper functions to your project (`helpers.php` in my case):

```
if (! function_exists('check_auth')) {
    function check_auth(): bool
    {
        if (! isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            return false;
        }

        if (! file_exists('current_user.txt') || filesize('current_user.txt') === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $trace = json_decode(file_get_contents('current_user.txt'));

        // You can write your own logic here.
        return (int) $trace->user_id === $_SESSION['user_id'] && (new DateTime($trace->created_at))->modify('+12 hours') > new Datetime('now');
    }
}

if (! function_exists('logout'))
{
    function logout()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            $trace = json_decode(file_get_contents('current_user.txt'));

            if ((int) $trace->user_id === $_SESSION['user_id']) {
                file_put_contents('current_user.txt', '');
            }

            unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        }
    }
}

if (! function_exists('redirect')) {
    function redirect(string $url, int $status_code = 303): void
    {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $status_code);
        die();
    }
}
```

3. Create a login page (`login.php` in my case):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// Start session.
session_start();

// Include helper functions.
require_once 'helpers.php';

// Redirect user to homepage/dashboard if authenticated.
if (check_auth()) {
    redirect('index.php');
    return;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=[DB_HOST];dbname=[DB_NAME];charset=utf8mb4', '[DB_USERNAME]', '[DB_PASSWORD]', [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ]);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['email']]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();

    if (! ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password))) {
        echo json_encode([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'These credentials don\'t match our records.',
        ]);
        return;
    }

    // Log user in if another is not authenticated.
    if (filesize('current_user.txt') === 0) {
        file_put_contents('current_user.txt', json_encode([
            'user_id'    => $user->id,
            'created_at' => (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]));

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;

        echo json_encode([
            'success' => true,
        ]);

        return;
    }

    $trace = json_decode(file_get_contents('current_user.txt'));

    // Log user in if the last authenticated user is himself/herself.
    if ((int) $trace->user_id === $user->id) {
        $trace->created_at = (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        file_put_contents('current_user.txt', json_encode($trace));

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;

        echo json_encode([
            'success' => true,
        ]);

        return;
    }

    // Ask user if he/she wants to take over.
    echo json_encode([
        'success'  => false,
        'takeover' => true,
        'message'  => 'Another user is logged in. Do you want to take over?',
    ]);

    return;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="form">
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span id="message" style="color: red;"></span>
        </div>
        <button>Log in</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#message').text('');

                $.post('login.php', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
                    const res = JSON.parse(response);

                    if (res.takeover) {
                        // Ask user if he/she wants to take over. If user confirms, run `confirmed()` function.
                        confirm(res.message) && confirmed();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (res.success) {
                        // Login is successful. Reload or redirect user to another page.
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        // Login failed. Incorrect email or password entered.
                        $('#message').text(res.message || '');
                    }
                });
            });

            function confirmed() {
                $.post('confirmed.php', function (response) {
                    const res = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(res.data);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Check if another user took over currently authenticated user in your pages (`index.php` in my case):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// Start session.
session_start();

// Include helper functions.
require_once 'helpers.php';

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (check_auth()): ?>
    Welcome friend.
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="/login.php">Log in</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Check if another user took over currently authenticated user in every 3 seconds.
        setInterval(function () {
            $.post('check.php', function (response) {
                let res = JSON.parse(response);
                if (! res.auth && res.redirect) {
                    location.replace(res.redirect);
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

5. Implement your check logic (`check.php` in my case):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// Start session.
session_start();

// Include helper functions.
require_once 'helpers.php';

if (! check_auth()) {
    logout();

    echo json_encode([
        'auth'     => false,
        'redirect' => 'login.php',
    ]);

    return;
}

echo json_encode([
    'auth' => true,
]);
```

6. Finally, create your action/function for the case when user confirms to take over (`confirmed.php` in my case):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// Start session.
session_start();

// Include helper functions.
require_once 'helpers.php';

/**
 * Run your action here if user confirms to take over another user.
 */
echo json_encode([
    'data' => 'User confirmed to take over another user.',
]);
```

Tested and works fine. But you should customize it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed suggestion. I was trying out your idea and when I run it locally on my end I see an issue after typing correct user and password. When I login for the first time it works fine but when I try logging again second time, it gives me error as `Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlogin/helpers.php on line 18`.  Not sure why I get that. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the problem is for the second time when it logs in `current_user.txt` file has two json object entries in it in same line so maybe not able to parse it properly after that?

Answer (score 2):

Here the basic concept.

- You need a central storage where the current active user `active_user_id` and `last_updated` is stored (database/file/memcache/redis whatever you want)
- You need to poll the current active user for each session - if the current user is not the active user he will logged out and notified, so he knows someone else took over.

Flow

- User loggs in

  - `$_SESSION['user_id'] = user_id`
  - IF: `$_SESSION['user_id']` !== `active_user_id`(central storage - see above) AND `last_updated` < 10s

    - TRUE: log in, update `active_user_id` to `$_SESSION['user_id']`; update `last_updated` to now; redirect to main-page
    - FALSE: show popup "Take over?" -> ok: same as TRUE from above, abort: close popup
- While logged-in call `check-active.php` every 5 seconds

`check-active.php` (pseudocode):

- IF: user_id from `$_SESSION['user_id']` === `active_user_id` from `storage`

  - TRUE: update `last_updated` in `storage`; return 'ok';
  - FALSE: call `session_destroy();` return 'failed';

`frontend` pseudocode (logged in):

- call `check-active.php` every 5 seconds
- handle result
- IF: result === 'ok'

  - TRUE: do nothing
  - FALSE: redirect to main page like 'main.php?message=' . urlencode('You got replaced')

> Why check for `last_updated` > 10s?

Because someone logged in could just close the browser, so we dont know if the session is still active or not. So we check `last_updated` (which will be updated every 5 seconds as long as the browser is still open). If `last_updated` is > 10s we consider it as "noone is currently active" so we dont have to ask to take over.

---

### Working example

Open [this](https://repl.it/repls/ConsiderableAttractiveMatter#index.php) - hit "run" (if not running).

Then open [this](https://considerableattractivematter--five-nine.repl.co/index.php) twice. One in a incognito tab, to get a secondary session to kick yourself out.

Disclaimer: This is absolutely experimental.

Comment: Overall I like the ideas in this one the best. The note at the bottom is very important to the OP, too. Never assume that someone is going to logout, always poll in a system such as this. Also for the OP, make sure your system supports multiple windows/tabs for the user so that you don't freak out the system if/when that happens.

Comment: @Pilan Sorry I was away for a while. Do you think you can provide an example in php with your above suggestion? It will be of great help to me.

Comment: @user1950349 added a working example - experimental

Comment: @Pilan I will take a look. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Pilan I tried clicking run but it doesn't do anything. Any idea why? I see on right this message `Hmmmm.... We Couldn't Reach Your Repl.....`

Comment: hit run... doens metter what it shows in the upper right corner

Answer (score 0):

This Sort Answer is  `Possible`.

You can do with `JavaScript` and `jQuery`.

use `setInterval`  **userA** and **userB** common users login check php

```
setInterval(function() {
    // codes here
},5000); // for 5 seconds
```

then confirmation from user when click function

```
$('#submit').on('click', function()
```

with `confirm` call `$.ajax` function

```
if(confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
    // $.ajax codes here
}return false;
```

**userB** try login `setInterval` send 20 seconds wait for response.

after 20 seconds that **userA** ip is set logout.

`setInterval` **userA** received **"logout"**  then call logout php.

it is basic **ip** , **user** and **logged** information in check php with database.

i just placed which function used for this? not full code.

Answer (score 0):

Note: code below is untested but should give you a basic idea of the way to go.

First of all, you should only be revoking write access from someone who currently has write access, so your first sql should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trace_users where open='true' && write_access = '1'";
```

Secondly, since you already only selecting users who have `'open' == "true"`, then checking again `if($row['open'] == "true") {` is redundant.

Thirdly, you should put the user name into the session for later manipulation and retrieval of logged-in user data.

Fourthly, you are executing the same query twice consecutively in the code below, so instead of:

```
if($result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
```

just put:

```
if($result1)
```

Now for a solution to your problem:

To avoid passing the name and password back and forth for a second login attempt after confirmation, we can use a token.
Also, at that point I would like to save the user name as I'm going to be using it so at line A put:

```
$_SESSION['login_token'] = sha1(time());
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
```

and we have to have a way of returning that token to the client and then back to the server so somewhere in your script you could have:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login_token']) && $_SESSION['login_token']) {
?>
<form id="confirm_form" action="login_script.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="login_token" value="<?= $_SESSION['login_token'] ?>">
</form>
<script>
// And the popup:
if (confirm('<?= addcslashes($message, "'/") ?>')) {
    document.getElementById('confirm_form').submit();
}
</script>
<?php
}
```

We also want the PHP script above to handle the session login which will also disconnect the other user so we will add:

```
if (isset($_POST['login_token'], $_SESSION['login_token']) && $_POST['login_token'] === $_SESSION['login_token']) {
    // block access to any write_access user
    // I am going to make an assumption here - that your write_access column can take the value "-1"
    // I am going to use it as a flag that means that this user needs to be told that his access has been revoked
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE trace_users SET write_access = '-1' where open='true'");

    $_SESSION['pageadmin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['login_token'] = null;
    $open = "true";
    $read_access = "1";
    $write_access = "1";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET open=?, read_access=?, write_access=? WHERE user_name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $open, $read_access, $write_access, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Finally we want a frontend script that checks change in permission:
I'm going to use polling + jQuery for this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('check_permissions.php', function(data) {
        if (data == '-1') {
            alert('your write access is revoked');
        }
    });
}, 5000);
</script>
```

and check_permissions.php is:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT write_access FROM trace_users WHERE user_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_name']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($status);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $status;

if ($status == -1) {
    // and update status of this user that he has no write permissions but no longer needs to be warned
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access = 0 WHERE user_name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```